# I need a class that creates a dictionary file that lives on disk

Tags: python

I want to create a very very large dictionary, and I'd like to store it on disk so as not to kill my memory. Basically, my needs are a cross between cPickle and the dict class, in that it's a class that Python treats like a dictionary, but happens to live on the disk.

My first thought was to create some sort of wrapper around a simple MySQL table, but I have to store types in the entries of the structure that MySQL can't even hope to support out of the box.

Comment: How large is "large"? Will you be mainly reading from the dictionary, or writing? Also, there may be a way to store the data in a MySQL table, but its hard to discuss without more details about your data. Is the data purely numeric? if not, what?

Comment: While the file is not going to grow quickly, there are no bounds on its size, and so I want to find a solution that allows me to store a file that can grow arbitrarily large over time, as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve) module, which works almost exactly like a dictionary:

```
import shelve
myshelf = shelve.open("filename") # Might turn into filename.db
myshelf["A"] = "First letter of alphabet"
print myshelf["A"]
# ...
myshelf.close()   # You should do this explicitly when you're finished
```

Note the caveats in the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve) about changing mutable values (lists, dicts, etc.) stored on a shelf (you can, but it takes a bit more fiddling). It uses (c)pickle and dbm under the hood, so it will cheerfully store anything you can pickle.

I don't know how well it performs relative to other solutions, but it doesn't require any custom code or third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [dbm](http://docs.python.org/library/dbm.html) in specific, and generally the entire [Data Persistence](http://docs.python.org/library/persistence.html) chapter in the manual.  Most key/value-store databases (gdbm, bdb, metakit, etc.) have a dict-like API which would probably serve your needs (and are fully embeddable so no need to manage an external database process).

Answer (score 0):

File IO is expensive in terms of CPU cycles. So my first thoughts would be in favor of a database.

However, you could also split your "English dictionary" across multiple files so that (say) each file holds words that start with a specific letter of the alphabet (therefore, you'll have 26 files).

Now, when you say `I want to create a very very large dictionary`, do you mean a python `dict` or an English dictionary with words and their definitions, stored in a `dict` (with words as keys and definitions as values)? The second can be easily implemented with cPickle, as you pointed out.

Again, if memory is your main concern, then you'll need to recheck the number of files you want to use, because, if you're pickling `dict`s into each file, then you want the `dict`s to not get too big

Perhaps a usable solution for you would be to do this (I am going to assume that all the English words are sorted):

1. Get all the words in the English language into one file.
2. Count how many such words there are and split them into as many files as you see fit, depending on how large the files get.
3. Now, these smaller files contain the words and their meanings

This is how this solution is useful:

Say that your problem is to lookup the definition of a particular word. Now, at runtime, you can read the first word in each file, and determine if the word that you are looking for is in the previous file that you read (you will need a loop counter to check if you are at the last file). Once you have determined which file the word you are looking for is in, then you can open that file and load the contents of that file into the `dict`.

It's a little difficult to offer a solution without knowing more details about the problem at hand.